Title of 80s or 90s UK TV Fantasy about computer game company
I am trying to remember the title of a UK drama series from the 80s or 90s about a computer game company. The firm created a fantasy board game. This then became a computer game and the partners fell out. The idealist partner ended up in an asylum. The series starts with him escaping and plotting his revenge against the business like partner. The idealist hacks into the firms computer and hides the profits. He then sets the business like one a series of tasks. There were couriers in black leather delivering clues. The series was pretty enjoyable and I would like to watch it again. If anyone could identify it that would be great.

You can search this list and see if you can find the game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_games

Sounds like "The One Game".  Here's the summary taken from its Wikipedia page:

Nick Thorne (Dillane) is a businessman who has achieved success by marketing games. He finds himself drawn into a "reality game" by his former business partner Magnus (Malahide), whom Nick had forced out of their games company after its initial success. Called "The One Game", this sees Nick take on a series of challenges which force him to explore his past, while both his professional and personal life come under threat.

There's a more detailed write-up and review here, which references some of the details you mentioned, such as the partner being sent to an asylum.
There was a UK DVD release a few years back, which now seems to be out-of-print.  It looks like it'll be reissued (in different packaging) in May 2016 though.
